# Delete entry in database by datetime with mysql and django?

Tags: python, sql, database, django, datetime

I'm using mysql with django 1.3 and I have posts stored in a database.  The posts are stored for a certain amount of time, say 7 days.  How can I delete a post when the duration(7 days) is up?  I'm not asking how to delete, but more how to determine when to delete?

I don't know if this is a good way of doing things, but one way I'm considering doing this is when the user looks up a post(query sent) and the duration is up, the post is deleted.  Also, when I do a search or browse and a list of posts if pulled from the database, I'll go through the list and delete the posts over the time limit.  What worries me about this implementation is when I pull a list, say ten posts, and 9 are over the time limit, I would have to get another list, and if there are posts over the limit in that list, I would have to get more .... etc. So one query could lead to a lot of queries and ultimately be very inefficient.  So is there a better way to do this?

Or maybe a whole better way of implementing this?

So basically, how can I implement a system so that a user will never see a post that is past its duration?

Not sure if I worded everything correctly, I'm really confused on how to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to set up a scheduled job to batch-delete old posts each night.  Setting up a scheduled job that runs in the Django environment is covered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job).

**The top answer:**

One solution that I have employed is to do this:

> 1) Create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands), e.g.
>
> ```
> python manage.py my_cool_command
> ```
>
> 2) Use cron to run my command at the required times.

Comment: hmm looked into this and django-celery, which way is better/more efficient? plus basicially I create the jobs and use a daemon bash to run everything?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you mark a date of expiry on the post?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    date_expire = models.DateField()
```

I would then extend the save method to add 7 days to the current date and save it to that field. Then when a user is retrieving the posts,

```
def some_view(request):
    # ....
    posts = Post.objects.filter(date_expire__gte=date_obj)
```

If you need to delete them, a simple way would be for the view to collect the expired post via a similar QuerySet and call delete(). Alternatively, you can also setup a script to run via cron for that kind of purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a daily cron job with a simple SQL DELETE by timestamp or a custom django management command.

Reference:

[Custom django commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

[Using contrab with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200001/using-crontab-with-django)