# Popular comments function

Tags: django

I have box with six most popular comments from last 4 days. I need to change it once at day (at midnight). How best to do this? I have function with getting most popular comments from last 4 days but how to update it only once at day?

24 hour cache with result is a solution?

Comment: Provide some information about what you have, how do you expect a person to help you?

Comment: @EmilDavtyan I have only queryset with six most popular comments from last 4 days in my views function(index) and I display this in template. But it is updated with every page request (not once at day)

Comment: Ok, then look at Brandon's answer, it seems to be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of choices. One is a simple [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200001/using-crontab-with-django) task that executes a Python function that updates your data at midnight on whatever day. The other is a [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) task that you can manage through Django admin to update the cache.

Comment: +1 for just using `cron` on things like this. People spent time and effort building an OS, we might as well all use it...

Comment: I agree. Celery is like swatting a fly with a cannon for this use case.

Comment: @Brandon Should I store ID of my six most popular comment in database and update this once a day? or how?

Comment: That's certainly a viable amd easy approach.