# Cronjob Django doesn't work?

Tags: python, django, cron

I have followd the following links for running a  cron job :

[django - cron](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cron)

[custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-management-commands/)

but all of these ways work if i run commands like:

or

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

or

```
   python manage.py runcron
```

but i don't want to do cron jobs without django server running
i mean i want to run django server and it automatically call a certain function by itself
during running of server for example every (say) 5 minutes.

Comment: have you looked into an django init script? [link](http://www.charleshooper.net/blog/controlling-django-apps-with-an-init-script)

Comment: does it work first time at start of running server?
if not please give me a simple example that call a function every 5 minutes

Comment: it allows you to daemonize django (run as a service essentially) you can start django on system startup. Or create a bash cron to check if django is running and start it.

Comment: so it can't help me to call a function periodically?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can't use django cron if django isn't running; so create a bash script to check if django is running and  if not start it.

```
MYPROG="myprog"
RESTART="myprog params"
PGREP="/usr/bin/pgrep"
# find myprog pid
$PGREP ${MYPROG}
# if not running
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   $RESTART
fi
```

Then for your cron:

```
*/5 * * * * /myscript.sh
```

This is off the cuff and not individualized to your setup but it's as good as any to start.

Comment: no even i start the django server
i need to type python manage.py runcron to do a job

Comment: it doesn't do it automatically

Comment: CRONJOBS = [
        ('*/1 * * * *', 'cron.views.my_scheduled_job')
    ]
to my settings.py
but it doesn't work

Comment: what I'm discussing will start the django server; I'm guessing you're looking to do something along the [lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200001/using-crontab-with-django)

Comment: yeah i have done that but that only works just once if i type manage.py runcrons by myself !

Comment: where should i type "*/5 * * * * /myscript.sh"?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can elaborate:

On Linux you'll use cron Windows will use at; these are system services not to be confused with Django. They are essentially scheduled tasks.

The custom management commands is essentially a script that you point the cron job to.

You'll need to do some homework on what a cron job is (if you're using Linux) and see how to schedule a reoccuring task and how to have it issue the custom command. This is my understanding of what you're trying to do. If it's not you need to clarify.